# Cakephp and Facebook authentication: Prevent to login automatically if users login facebook in browser

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, authentication

I am using WebTechNicks [Facebook plugin for Cakephp](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more). 
This is my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Time', 'Number', 'Javascript','Facebook.Facebook');
var $components = array('Auth', 'Cookie', 'RequestHandler','Email', 'Facebook.Connect','Session');
function beforeFilter() {
        $fb_user = $this->Connect->user();
        $this->set("fb_user",$this->Connect->user());
        if($this->Auth->user()) {
            $user = $this->User->find('first', array(   'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
                                                                                                    'fields'=>array('User.id', 'User.facebook_id'),
                                                                                                    'contain' => ''));
            //$this->writelog($user);
            $this->set('user_fb_id',$user['User']['facebook_id']);
        }
}
```

In view:

```
<?php if($session->check('Auth.User')):?>
     <?php if (isset($user_fb_id) && $user_fb_id ==0):?>
            <?php echo $facebook->login('Sync with facebook'); ?>
     <?php endif;?>
     <?php if (empty($fb_user) || $fb_user==null):?> 
          <a href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>users/logout">Logout</a>
     <?php else:?>
          <?php echo $facebook->logout() ?>
     <?php endif;?>

<?php else:?>
      <?php echo $facebook->login('Login with facebook') ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>users/login">Login</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

User can login to my web via facebook or normal login. 
**My problem is:** 
If users login facebook in their browser, then they go to my web (in another tab), it login **automatically**. 
I don't want this, users need to click to "Login with facebook" button to login. 
Who can help me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would defeat the purpose of using Facebooks single sign on wouldn't it? It also isn't logical to use the facebook connect plugin if they have to login again.

The plugin checks with FB to confirm there is a valid session. It is basically opening an invisible facebook connection for authentication. When it sees that the user already has an active session it just returns this session.

In all fairness they do have to click Login With Facebook the first time they visit your site to give your application access to their data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know, but sometime user login facebook as account A and they want to login my web as account B. What would they do?

Comment: @NamLe they should click logout on your site then log back in.

Comment: Oh. when they click logout on my site, do they must to logout facebook too?

Comment: @NamLe When they logout of your site it will log them out of facebook as well.